# fullpage.js with ui-tabs issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

My usecase is as below - 
I have horizontal tabs on top (that uses jquery-ui - ui-tabs)

First       Second    Third

Each tab is a hyperlink.
When "second" Tab is clicked it pulls up a page where I use the fullpage.js
That page has 3 sections. The first section pulls up with the 3 tabs on the top.

When user is scrolling, the second section shows up with part of first section on top(that height kind of matches the tab height in first section)

I do have scrollOverflow:true.

How do I fix that please.

It looks like this
[image: initial display]

[image: after scrolling display]

Comment: Can one of the gurus have a look at this please

Comment: Please see this jsfiddle link, to see this use case
http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/736/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following styles:

```
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#tabs{
    padding: 0;
}
#tabs ul{
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;
}
```

[Demo online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/755/)